# Is it possible to upload files in a website server not set-up in FTP in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, upload

I'm creating a web tool in ASP.NET(c#) which can upload images to different sites and one of the sites is not set-up in FTP. Is it possible to upload files in the that site(with credentials)? If it is, can you please enlighten me on the process?

Thanks...

Comment: HTTP supports file uploads...

Answer (score 2):

You could look at creating an image admin page which uses the [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [fileupload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control.  It allows the user to do exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control. But it will only allow upload data to the web server.

But if you need to save file to a different server, you will probably need handle the `POST` request.

I think this article about [Writing Server-Side Upload Code](http://www.aurigma.com/docs/iu/WritingServerSideUploadCode.htm) may help you.